# JavaFX - what to extend my "windows" from, stage, scene, pane?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I quoted window because I am not referring to any Class in the API, just the literal meaning of window (frame, panel, form whatever).

In Swing I used to make a base class which extended from `JPanel` then I extended all of my view related classes from that base class. this was very helpful because I could place these panels either on their own `JFrames` or inside in another panel in a `MyPanel` on a frame. In a way how they were shown was irrelevant to class itself. And each of them could have different layout (contrary to extending from a JavaFX layout pane)

How do I do this in Java-FX?

Comment: *"In Swing I used to make a base class which extended from `JPanel`.."* Then you were already doing it wrong. The only valid case I've seen for extending `JPanel` was to do custom painting. Prefer [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: the add method of all of swing classes expects a jcomponent. It was just more convinent to use add(myobject) instead of add(myobject.getSomething()). What problems do you think i have faced(and not know about it:) )  because of inheritance?

Comment: The link explains it better than I could be bothered (even trying). Ultimately, code as you like. I'll leave the comment there as a warning to others.

Answer (score 1):

You can extends the `Pane` class, which is the base class of all panes in JavaFX. This does not perform any layout.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html

Edit: I realized that you can also use a more general class `Region`. This class can contain other nodes and can also be styled.

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html

So for example if you need a new pane, you extend `YourCustomRegion`

```
public class YourPane extends YourCustomRegion {

   public YourPane() {
      getChildren().add(new HBox()); //you can add children with this method
   }

}
```

And if you need something common in all your custom panes you can do that in `YourCustomRegion` which is extended from `Region`.

Comment: and then can it have GridPane,BorderPane etc as its root node? I assumed it would have to have absolute positinoning and sizing like null layout swing.

Comment: I updated my answer with another option that is better for you I think. It uses the Region class instead of the Pane. But I really think you should just use the sublcasses of Pane, these manage layout for you.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried. this(both  pane and Region) actualy works but I ended up not inheriting any FX class . instead , My base class will have rootnode,stage and scene as members and it will lazily create stage and scene depending on how it will be shown. And I use a type parameter for 'rootNode' to avoid the need of casting in subclasses.